# Want to scrape all members profile links from the given site

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://iacts.org/members/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

for link in soup.find('div',id_='members-dir-list'):
  for link1 in link.find_all('div',class_='item'):
     for link2 in link1.find_all('a'):
        for link3 in link2.find('href'):
            print(link3.text)
```

Not getting members links, want to scrape the members profile links from the given site.

Comment: The site has no `div` div with the corresponding `id`. Are you using the correct link and `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below. You can open chrome developer tools (F12) and see what form data was send to the post request when clicking the search button. Then you mimic the requests by passing the data in requests.

```
import requests
import lxml
from lxml import html

data = {
    "iacts_search": "Search",
    "bp_profile_search": "true"
}

r = requests.post('http://iacts.org/members/', data=data)

tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

member_list = tree.xpath('//*[@id="members-list"]//div[@class="item-title"]//a')

# print(len(member_list))

for member in member_list:
    print(member.get('href'))
```

Results:

```
http://iacts.org/members/Jc
http://iacts.org/members/Jc2
http://iacts.org/members/Ramesh-test
http://iacts.org/members/Raj
http://iacts.org/members/Arvind
http://iacts.org/members/Nhf
http://iacts.org/members/Man
http://iacts.org/members/Srujan
http://iacts.org/members/Vikas
http://iacts.org/members/Manohar
http://iacts.org/members/Sanjeeva Rao
http://iacts.org/members/Atul Kumar Gupta
http://iacts.org/members/Charlesmundwp
http://iacts.org/members/Amjad M
http://iacts.org/members/Dr Mrithyunjaya V
http://iacts.org/members/Siddharth
```

Comment: But its not giving full link of a member.

Comment: Its not giving full link of a member.The link contains Name and particular Id @Y Y

Comment: updated answer with results. can you show an example of a full link?

Comment: http://iacts.org/members/Rajan-561b55fcd2851-561b56067ee09                http://iacts.org/members/Rupesh%20-1075-561b55fd85221-561b56074d3ae @Y Y

Comment: try to replace the url to http://iacts.org/iacts-member-search/ to get the full link @dhananjay